# Formulate n different vector dot products as a matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is there a smart way to formulate the following as one matrix multiplication, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^nh_i \sum_{k=1}^KH_{ik} p_{ik}$$
as something like $\mathbf{h*(H*p)}$?

The only way I can think of is to augment $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ with 0 to be n-by-nK, nK-by-nK matrices respectively.

Comment: This appears to be mathematics rather than stats, and likely belongs on math.SE.

Comment: @Glen_b, I see. I thought about where I should put this too. Thanks. Regardless, it got some good answers. I will post accordingly next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also if you define $*$ as coordinate-wise multiplication, and $\mathbf{1_k}$ as the $k$ dimension column vector,
$$
\mathbf{ h^T (H * p) 1_k }
$$
does the trick.  And it should be fewer operations.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbf{H}$  and $\mathbf{p}$ are  $n\times K$ matrices and $\mathbf{h}$ is $n\times 1$ vector then you write this product as

$$\mathbf{h}^T\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{H}\mathbf{p}^T)$$

where $\mathrm{diag}$ is the operator which takes a matrix and returns its main diagonal as a vector.

Comment: This indeed does the operation but is quite redundant in the operations.